# How to make Java load imported classes from another package?

Tags: java, classloader, package

I want to load a list of classes dynamically.
For example i have in directory /hereAreMyClasses:
class1.class
class2.class
class3.class

Iterating over these classes with a ClassLoader and loading them works just fine.

The problem now is, that one of these classes (let's say, class2) imports some classes from another location / another package.

```
import other.package.someClass;

public class class2 {
  //stuff
}
```

This works fine on compile-time but when i run the program, i get an NoClassDefFoundError for someClass when i call

```
Class<?> clazz = clazzLoader.loadClass("class2");
```

How do i get the ClassLoader to also load the needed imported classes?

**EDIT**

Problem solved, thanks to the answers i noticed, that i was missing the classpath-definition when calling my program.

Comment: An `import` statement is only a compile time concept meant for scoping. It has no run time effect on a program.

Comment: import doesn't do anything except save you typing.  people often confuse it with class loading.  that's not what it's doing.

Answer (score -1):

**Please try to do it on your own before looking into this Solution. Nathan has told the right thing.**

You have to add the other directory to classpath while compiling and executing your Java code. A simple example is like this:

**Folder 1:**

```
directory1/SourceCode1.java
```

**Folder 2:**

```
directory2/com/dir2/SourceCode2.class
```

Suppose SourceCode1.java has package name as com.dir1:

```
package com.dir1;

import com.dir2.SourceCode2;

public class SourceCode1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SourceCode2 used in this class
    }
}
```

Then while compiling and executing you have to use -cp command which tells the compiler and interpreter to find the classpath at specified locations.

While compiling:

```
javac -d . -cp .:<directory2 path> SourceCode1.java
```

While executing:

```
java -cp .:<directory2 path> com.dir1.SourceCode1
```

Comment: `SourceCode1.java` is in the wrong directory, according to its own package statement.

Comment: SourceCode1.java is not in wrong directory. A directory while compilation has nothing got to do with the package name. This is just a demonstration of where the files are and how to understand their path and execution.